# Writing in command line an export procedure for mysql with R

Tags: mysql, r, cmd

I'm exporting query results from mysql with the command line:

```
SET sql=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.1.4\mysql.exe
SET p_s=C:\Rtools\bin\sed.exe

"%sql%" --skip-secure-auth --host=xxx.xxx.xx.x --user=myuser --password=mypass  mydb <c:/Temp/my_query.txt | "%p_s%" 's/\t/;/g'  >  C:/Temp/myfile.txt
```

Thats works very good for me. Now I want to write this procedure in R. I'm trying a thing like:

```
b<-"SET sql=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench CE 6.1.4\\mysql.exe"
a<-"SET p_s=C:\\Rtools\\bin\\sed.exe"
s<-  ' "%sql%" --skip-secure-auth --host=xxx.xxx.xx.x --user=myuser--password=mypass  mydb <c:/Temp/my_query.txt | "%p_s%" \'s/\\t/;/g\'  >  C:/Temp/myfile.txt'

system(a)
system(b)
system(s)
```

But that's not working. If I run:

```
try(system(a, intern = TRUE))
```

It returns:`Error in system(a, intern = TRUE) : 'SET' not found`
Some advices?

Comment: it wouldn't do what you want it to do anyway with three separate `system` calls. why not write all three lines to a `.BAT` file (in a temp dir) and execute that batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved creating a .BAT file as suggest by @hrbrmstr

```
p1<-"SET sql=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench CE 6.1.4\\mysql.exe"
p2<-"SET p_s=C:\\Rtools\\bin\\sed.exe"

host<-"xxx.xxx.xx.x"
user<-"myuser"
password<-"mypass"
db<-"mydb"
sep<-";"
file<-"C:/Temp/myfile.txt"

query<- "SELECT * FROM mytable limit 100;"

cmd<-paste('"%sql%" --skip-secure-auth --host=',host,' --user=',user,' --password=',password,' ',db,' <c:/Temp/query.sql | "%p_s%" \'s/\\t/',sep , '/g\'  >', file,sep="")
cmd<-paste(p1,p2,cmd, sep="\n")

setwd("c:\\temp")
write(query,"query.sql")
write(cmd,"mycommand.bat")
system("mycommand.bat")
```